# get highest div

Tags: jquery, html

I saw a lot of things on stack overflor to get the highest div, only non of them where working for me. I need to get the height of the div preview_txt.

```
<div class="headline" data-rating="0.482005543693" onclick="javascript:showArticle(1076);" style="display: none; ">
    <div class="headline_txt">
        <h1>#3726: Meryl Streep schittert in The Iron Lady- alle recensies op een rijtje</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="preview_txt">
        <p>
            De eerste foto's van actrice Meryl Streep als de Britse voormalig premier Margaret Thatcher
            <a href="http://www.guardian.co.uk/film/2011/feb/08/meryl-streep-margaret-thatcher-iron-lady#">
                leidden
            </a>
            vorig jaar al tot een stortvloed aan publiciteit. Nu is
            <a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1007029/">
                <em>The Iron Lady</em>
            </a>
             er dan ook echt. Vanaf vandaag draait de film in de Nederlandse bioscopen. Lees hier alle recensies. 
            <!--more-->
        </p>
    </div>                  
</div>
```

From the things i saw arround i think i liked this one the most:

```
var maxHeadLineHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, $("#headline").map(
    function(){
        return $(this).height();
    }
));

console.log("maxHeadLineHeight: "+maxHeadLineHeight);
```

But that gives me:

`Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type`

I also tried it like:

```
"#headline .preview_txt"
```

while where at it, setting the height for each headline div will be next but that probably won't be that different (by getting the objects).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems with the code:

#### 1. Your selector is wrong.

`$("#headline")` will find an element with an **id** of `headline`, not a **class** of `headline`.

Try this instead:

```
$(".headline").map(...
```

#### 2. You forgot to include `.get()` after `.map()`

I'm not sure why this is important, but examples similar to the code you've posted all say you need to call:

```
$('<someSelectorHere>').map(function () { /* some mapping code here ... */ })
    .get(); // <-- The part you missed - won't work without it
```

See this example:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5052710/232593

*Edit:*

According to comments and the jQuery docs, it seems that calling [the `.get()` method](http://api.jquery.com/get/) is important because the objects returned by jQuery aren't truly arrays - they just masquerade as arrays.  While some browsers are okay with this (seemingly Firefox), other browsers can't deal with it.  So you need to add the `.get()` to convert to a real array and support those browsers.

#### Demo of a working version of the code you provided:

- http://jsfiddle.net/zvu2n/

The Javascript from that demo:

```
var headlineHeights = $(".headline").map(function() {
    return $(this).height();
}).get();

var maxHeadLineHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, headlineHeights);

alert("maxHeadLineHeight: " + maxHeadLineHeight);
```

Comment: @anonymous downvoter: Tell me what is wrong with my answer. Everything I said was true - I tried it out by hand and made a working demo. All the examples I found (found others on google too, but didn't bother to refernce them) all said to use `.get()` after the map function. When I tried it out in jsfiddle under both IE and Chrome, it wouldn't work properly without it.

Comment: thanks man, this works great, even better that i also can get the array. Not that i need it but still :)

Comment: @clankill3r: Glad to help :)  If I figure out what that `.get()` is about, I'll update the answer to let you know *why* it needs to be included.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were wrong about the .get(), and now I can't change it to an upvote (too long ago apparantly). Btw, reason is that Firefox accepts array-like objects as arguments, while other browsers want a real array (and jQuery doesn't return real arrays, the get() converts it to one).

Comment: @Johan: Made an edit to incorporate your comments, and a link to `.get()` (which also talks about jQuery objects vs arrays).  You should be able to change the vote now if you would like.  I'm fine with downvotes, just not unexplained ones :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, that seems to work in firebug though. On this page, the following code gives an answer (625 in my browser at least).

```
Math.max.apply(Math, $("#question").map(
 function(){
   return $(this).height();
 }
));
```

or apparently for other browsers

```
Math.max.apply(Math, $("#question").map(
 function(){
   return $(this).height();
 }
).get());
```

But it's a bit strange, since in your code you check an ID (which will be 0 or 1 element), and maxing that is kinda obvious. So I think something else is going wrong. I'd expect a good answer if #question is replaced by .headline .preview_text