# Obtain smallest value from array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, min

Array justPrices has values such as:

```
[0] = 1.5
[1] = 4.5
[2] = 9.9.
```

How do I return the smallest value in the array?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052673/jquery-min-max-property-from-array-of-elements) can help you.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov: I think your brother answered it pretty well

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Jon Resig illustrated in [this article](http://ejohn.org/blog/fast-javascript-maxmin/) how this could be achieved by extending the Array prototype and invoking the underlying [Math.min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) method which unfortunately doesn't take an array but a variable number of arguments:

```
Array.min = function( array ){
    return Math.min.apply( Math, array );
};
```

and then:

```
var minimum = Array.min(array);
```

Comment: Is there any reason, why you don't recommend prototyping?

Comment: @MarekSebera, I didn't write the article, I just linked to it. Ask John Resig why.

Comment: @MarekSebera, while I like to extend the `Array.prototype` myself, I recommend treading with care. `for..in` loops can pick up functions in addition to the numbered indices, and a careless programmer could easily break code.

Comment: I find more cool @c69 solution adapted to the prototype: Array.prototype.min = function(){return this.sort()[0]}

Comment: @Davsket Math.min is O(N) where sort is O(N log N). It is cute but slower; much slower on large arrays.

Comment: @Davsket, `Array.prototype.sort` will impact the original array object by changing all the indices, whereas a valid `Array.prototype.min` function would not have such side effects.

Comment: @zzzzBov yeah, I know, but it's interesting, an even slower but safer solution could use slice before sorting, but is totally obvious that using Math.min is the better way. In fact... I up-voted this that day ;)

Answer (score 244):

The tersest expressive code to find the minimum value is probably [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

```js
const arr = [14, 58, 20, 77, 66, 82, 42, 67, 42, 4]
const min = Math.min(...arr)
console.log(min)
```

---

Rest parameters are essentially a convenient shorthand for [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) when you don't need to change the function's context:

```js
var arr = [14, 58, 20, 77, 66, 82, 42, 67, 42, 4]
var min = Math.min.apply(Math, arr)
console.log(min)
```

---

This is also a great use case for [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const arr = [14, 58, 20, 77, 66, 82, 42, 67, 42, 4]
const min = arr.reduce((a, b) => Math.min(a, b))
console.log(min)
```

It may be tempting to pass `Math.min` directly to `reduce`, however the callback receives additional parameters:

```
callback (accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array)
```

In this particular case it may be a bit verbose. `reduce` is particularly useful when you have a collection of complex data that you want to aggregate into a single value:

```js
const arr = [{name: 'Location 1', distance: 14}, {name: 'Location 2', distance: 58}, {name: 'Location 3', distance: 20}, {name: 'Location 4', distance: 77}, {name: 'Location 5', distance: 66}, {name: 'Location 6', distance: 82}, {name: 'Location 7', distance: 42}, {name: 'Location 8', distance: 67}, {name: 'Location 9', distance: 42}, {name: 'Location 10', distance: 4}]
const closest = arr.reduce(
  (acc, loc) =>
    acc.distance < loc.distance
      ? acc
      : loc
)
console.log(closest)
```

---

And of course you can always use classic iteration:

```js
var arr,
  i,
  l,
  min

arr = [14, 58, 20, 77, 66, 82, 42, 67, 42, 4]
min = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY
for (i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
  min = Math.min(min, arr[i])
}
console.log(min)
```

...but even classic iteration can get a modern makeover:

```js
const arr = [14, 58, 20, 77, 66, 82, 42, 67, 42, 4]
let min = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY
for (const value of arr) {
  min = Math.min(min, value)
}
console.log(min)
```

Comment: The first part of the *explanation* (not the code) in this answer is confusing/incorrect. The claim "Rest parameters are essentially a convenient shorthand for Function.prototype.apply" should be replaced with: The [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax (`...arr`) is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays (or properties from objects) into distinct variables. So, `Math.min(...arr)` is a **destructuring assignment** that spreads the array into distinct variables.

Answer (score 52):

I find that the easiest way to return the smallest value of an array is to use the Spread Operator on Math.min() function.

```js
return Math.min(...justPrices);
//returns 1.5 on example given
```

The page on MDN helps to understand it better: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min

A little extra:
This also works on Math.max() function

return Math.max(...justPrices);
//returns 9.9 on example given.

Hope this  helps!

Comment: best answer here!

Answer (score 13):

**Update:** use Darin's / John Resig answer, just keep in mind that you dont need to specifiy thisArg for `min`, so `Math.min.apply(null, arr)` will work just fine.

---

or you can just **sort** the array and get value #1:
`[2,6,7,4,1].sort()[0]`

[!] But without supplying custom number sorting function, this will only work in one, very limited case: **positive numbers less than 10**. See how it would break:

```
var a = ['', -0.1, -2, -Infinity, Infinity, 0, 0.01, 2, 2.0, 2.01, 11, 1, 1e-10, NaN];

// correct: 
a.sort( function (a,b) { return a === b ? 0 : a < b ? -1: 1} );
//Array [NaN, -Infinity, -2, -0.1, 0, "", 1e-10, 0.01, 1, 2, 2, 2.01, 11, Infinity]

// incorrect:
a.sort();
//Array ["", -0.1, -2, -Infinity, 0, 0.01, 1, 11, 1e-10, 2, 2, 2.01, Infinity, NaN]
```

And, also, **array is changed in-place**, which might not be what you want.

Comment: or [2,6,7,4,1].sort()[0] if you want to preserve the array objects

Comment: "positive numbers less than 10" - why? Does it use string comparison by default?

Answer (score 12):

Imagine you have this array:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
```

ES6 way:

```
var min = Math.min(...arr); //min=1
```

ES5 way:

```
var min = Math.min.apply(null, arr); //min=1
```

If you using D3.js, there is a handy function which does the same, but will ignore **undefined** values and also check the natural order:

> **d3.max(array[, accessor])**
>
> Returns the maximum value in the given array using natural order. If
>   the array is empty, returns undefined. An optional accessor function
>   may be specified, which is equivalent to calling array.map(accessor)
>   before computing the maximum value.
>
> Unlike the built-in Math.max, this method ignores undefined values;
>   this is useful for ignoring missing data. In addition, elements are
>   compared using natural order rather than numeric order. For example,
>   the maximum of the strings [“20”, “3”] is “3”, while the maximum of
>   the numbers [20, 3] is 20.

And this is the source code for D3 v4:

```
export default function(values, valueof) {
  var n = values.length,
      i = -1,
      value,
      max;

  if (valueof == null) {
    while (++i < n) { // Find the first comparable value.
      if ((value = values[i]) != null && value >= value) {
        max = value;
        while (++i < n) { // Compare the remaining values.
          if ((value = values[i]) != null && value > max) {
            max = value;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  else {
    while (++i < n) { // Find the first comparable value.
      if ((value = valueof(values[i], i, values)) != null && value >= value) {
        max = value;
        while (++i < n) { // Compare the remaining values.
          if ((value = valueof(values[i], i, values)) != null && value > max) {
            max = value;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return max;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

ES6 is the way of the future.

```
arr.reduce((a, b) => Math.min(a, b));
```

I prefer this form because it's easily generalized for other use cases

Comment: bang on... answer tho is for min not max ;)

Comment: Maybe the question is wrong and it's for max... twice it's been answered and twice it's been for max... just sayin`          ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 5):

```
var array =[2,3,1,9,8];
var minvalue = array[0]; 
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i]<minvalue)
    {
        minvalue = array[i];
    }

}
  console.log(minvalue);
```

Answer (score 3):

Possibly an easier way?

Let's say justPrices is mixed up in terms of value, so you don't know where the smallest value is.

```
justPrices[0] = 4.5
justPrices[1] = 9.9
justPrices[2] = 1.5
```

Use sort.

```
justPrices.sort();
```

It would then put them in order for you. (Can also be done alphabetically.) The array then would be put in ascending order.

```
justPrices[0] = 1.5
justPrices[1] = 4.5
justPrices[2] = 9.9
```

You can then easily grab by the first index.

```
justPrices[0]
```

I find this is a bit more useful than what's proposed above because what if you need the lowest 3 numbers as an example? You can also switch which order they're arranged, more info at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Comment: very smart solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can use min method in Math object!

```js
const abc = [50, 35, -25, -6, 91]; 
    
function findMin(args) {   
    return Math.min(...args); 
} 
    
console.log(findMin(abc));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at the other answers that were given before. Your approach is mentioned there already. In order to keep the site clear and make it easy to find answers, we try to avoid double answers.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function smallest(){
  if(arguments[0] instanceof Array)
    arguments = arguments[0];

  return Math.min.apply( Math, arguments );
}
function largest(){
  if(arguments[0] instanceof Array)
    arguments = arguments[0];

  return Math.max.apply( Math, arguments );
}
var min = smallest(10, 11, 12, 13);
var max = largest([10, 11, 12, 13]);

console.log("Smallest: "+ min +", Largest: "+ max);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the benefit of doing this over calling Math.min directly?

Comment: @jiggzson See Darin Dimitrov description "Math.min method which unfortunately doesn't take an array but a variable number of arguments". This solutions work well with both array and variable number of arguments.

Comment: I was referring to your prior example. I noticed that you edited to detect for an array. I imagine that was your original intention. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have an easy-to-understand solution for this, using only the basics of javaScript.

```
function myFunction() {
            var i = 0;
            var smallestNumber = justPrices[0];
            for(i = 0; i < justPrices.length; i++) {
                if(justPrices[i] < smallestNumber) {
                    smallestNumber = justPrices[i];
                }
            }
            return smallestNumber;
        }
```

The variable `smallestNumber` is set to the first element of `justPrices`, and the for loop loops through the array (I'm just assuming that you know how a for loop works; if not, look it up). If an element of the array is smaller than the current `smallestNumber` (which at first is the first element), it will replace it's value. When the whole array has gone through the loop, `smallestNumber` will contain the smallest number in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a variant of Darin Dimitrov’s answer that doesn’t modify the `Array` prototype:

```
const applyToArray = (func, array) => func.apply(Math, array)

applyToArray(Math.min, [1,2,3,4]) // 1
applyToArray(Math.max, [1,2,3,4]) // 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function tinyFriends() {
    let myFriends = ["Mukit", "Ali", "Umor", "sabbir"]
    let smallestFridend = myFriends[0];
    for (i = 0; i < myFriends.length; i++) {
        if (myFriends[i] < smallestFridend) {
            smallestFridend = myFriends[i];
        }
    }
    return smallestFridend   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A super-easy way to find the smallest value would be

```js
Array.prototype.min = function(){
    return Math.min.apply(Math,this);
};
```

To call the function, just use the name of the array and add .min()

```js
Array.prototype.min = function(){
    return Math.min.apply(Math,this);
};
var arr = [12,56,126,-1,5,15];
console.log(   arr.min()   );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Underscore or Lodash you can get the minimal value using this kind of simple functional pipeline

```
_.chain([7, 6, -1, 3, 2]).sortBy().first().value()
// -1
```

You also have the `.min` function

```
_.min([7, 6, -1, 3, 2])
// -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that will detect the lowest value in an array of numbers.

```
//function for finding smallest value in an array
function arrayMin(array){
    var min = array[0];
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(min < array[i]){
            min = min;
        }else if (min > array[i]){
            min = array[i + 1];
        }else if (min == array[i]){
            min = min;
        }
    }
    return min;
};
```

call it in this way:

```
var fooArray = [1,10,5,2];
var foo = arrayMin(fooArray);
```

(Just change the second `else if` result from: `min = min` to `min = array[i]`
 if you want numbers which reach the smallest value to replace the original number.)

Comment: This is terrible code. It only works if the min value is first, otherwise you get IndexOutOfRangeException. And all the "min = min" is probably a not yet invented anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive way on how to do it using ternary operators both for the recursion and decision whether you came across a min number or not.

```
const findMin = (arr, min, i) => arr.length === i ? min :
  findMin(arr, min = arr[i] < min ? arr[i] : min, ++i)
```

Code snippet:

```js
const findMin = (arr, min, i) => arr.length === i ? min :
  findMin(arr, min = arr[i] < min ? arr[i] : min, ++i)
  
const arr = [5, 34, 2, 1, 6, 7, 9, 3];
const min = findMin(arr, arr[0], 0)
console.log(min);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any Readymade Function, you can do it like this:

here is the function which takes an array and return smallest value from the array.

```
function findSmallest(passedArray){
    let smallestNumber = passedArray[0];
    passedArray.forEach((a, i) => {
        if(passedArray[i+1] < smallestNumber){
            smallestNumber = passedArray[i+1];
        }else{
            smallestNumber;
        }
    });
    return smallestNumber;
}
```

Or you can do it easily with `Math` function

```
let a = Math.min(5, 10);
let b = Math.min(0, 150, 30, 20, 38);
let c = Math.min(-5, 10);
let d = Math.min(-5, -10);
let e = Math.min(1.5, 2.5);
```

The result:

```
5
0
-5
-10
1.5
```

Answer (score -2):

For anyone out there who needs this I just have a feeling.
(Get the smallest number with multi values in the array)
Thanks to Akexis answer.

if you have let's say an array of
Distance and ID and ETA in minutes
So you do push maybe in for loop or something

```
Distances.push([1.3, 1, 2]); // Array inside an array.
```

And then when It finishes, do a sort

```
Distances.sort();
```

So this will sort upon the first thing which is Distance here.
Now we have the closest or the least is the first you can do

```
Distances[0] // The closest distance or the smallest number of distance. (array).
```

Comment: The default Array.sort() sorts on string value, not numeric value, so Distances[0] won't necessarily be the lowest value.