# how to find the minimum value in a key/value data structure?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How would you find the minimum value in this object in d3?

{Mon: 3.7, Tues: 1.2, Wed: 2.4, Thurs: 9.6....}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obtain smallest value from array in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934877/obtain-smallest-value-from-array-in-javascript)

Comment: This is not an array, it's an object. All you need to do is check every value of the object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the value itself, use [d3.min](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_min) and [d3.values](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_values):

```
var obj = {Mon: 3.7, Tues: 1.2, Wed: 1.4, Thurs: 9.6};
var min = d3.min(d3.values(obj)); // 1.2
```

If you want to know the member that contains the min value, use [d3.entries](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_entries) and [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
min = d3.entries(obj).reduce(function(memo, item){
  return memo.value > item.value ? memo : item;
}); // {key: "Tues", value: 1.2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [underscorejs max](http://underscorejs.org/#max):

```
var obj = {Mon: 3.7, Tues: 1.2, Wed: 2.4, Thurs: 9.6};
var max = _.max(obj); // 9.6
```

and [userscorejs min](http://underscorejs.org/#min):

```
var obj = {Mon: 3.7, Tues: 1.2, Wed: 2.4, Thurs: 9.6};
var min = _.min(obj ); // 1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a loop that goes through the object and compares its values. Heres a code:

```
var obj= {Mon: 3.7, Tues: 1.2, Wed: 2.4, Thurs: 9.6};
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
var leastEl = obj[keys[0]];

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if (leastEl > obj[keys[i]]) {
        leastEl = obj[keys[i]];   
    }
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lithium182/xZS6s/)

edit: and yeah - as someone already stated above - your given example doesnt have any array inside, it has an object.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var obj = {Mon: 3.7,Tues: 1.2,Wed: 1.4}
        var min;
        for(var x in obj){

            if(min == undefined || obj[x]<min){
                min=obj[x];
            }

        }
        console.log(min);
```