# jQuery get highest value in array url parameters value

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a url array parameters that has number values.
I've do research but I didn't find nothing.

So here is my array url: `units[1]=5&grade[1]=1.25&units[2]=3&grade[2]=1.50&units[3]=2&grade[3]=2.50`

What I need is to get the lowest value of `units` and `grade`

In short, it will display: `1.25` as lowest grade and `2` as lowest unit

Is it possible to do it with that kind of string? Thank you!

Comment: what is this ->units[1]=5&grade[1]=1.25&units[2]=3&grade[2]=1.50&units[3]=2&grade[3]=2.50

A URL ? or just a String in the javascript?

Comment: Why send like this ??? use post

Comment: suppose you have the index upto units[500]

Answer (score 1):

I used the parseParams from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/v92Pv/23/) via [jquery.parseparams.js](https://gist.github.com/kares/956897)

```js
/* helper functions */

(function ($) { var re = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g; var decode = function (str) { return decodeURIComponent(str.replace(/\+/g, ' ')); }; $.parseParams = function (query) { function createElement(params, key, value) { key = key + ''; if (key.indexOf('.') !== -1) { var list = key.split('.'); var new_key = key.split(/\.(.+)?/)[1]; if (!params[list[0]]) params[list[0]] = {}; if (new_key !== '') { createElement(params[list[0]], new_key, value); } else console.warn('parseParams :: empty property in key "' + key + '"'); } else if (key.indexOf('[') !== -1) { var list = key.split('['); key = list[0]; var list = list[1].split(']'); var index = list[0]; if (index == '') { if (!params) params = {}; if (!params[key] || !$.isArray(params[key])) params[key] = []; params[key].push(value); } else { if (!params) params = {}; if (!params[key] || !$.isArray(params[key])) params[key] = []; params[key][parseInt(index)] = value; } } else { if (!params) params = {}; params[key] = value; } } query = query + ''; if (query === '') query = window.location + ''; var params = {}, e; if (query) { if (query.indexOf('#') !== -1) { query = query.substr(0, query.indexOf('#')); } if (query.indexOf('?') !== -1) { query = query.substr(query.indexOf('?') + 1, query.length); } else return {}; if (query == '') return {}; while (e = re.exec(query)) { var key = decode(e[1]); var value = decode(e[2]); createElement(params, key, value); } } return params; }; })(jQuery);

Array.prototype.min = function() {
  return Math.min.apply(null, this);
};
function getArr(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) { return obj[key]; })
}

/* Actual code */

// change the string to for example location.href to get your URL
var url = "http://example.com/?units[1]=5&grade[1]=1.25&units[2]=3&grade[2]=1.50&units[3]=2&grade[3]=2.50";
var arrs = $.parseParams(url); // now the arrays are stored as arrs={ unit:[], grade:[] }

var unitArr = getArr(arrs.units),gradeArr=getArr(arrs.grade); // extact the values only

console.log(unitArr.min(),gradeArr.min()); // grab the min of each
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

### Steps

#### Parse URL arguments to JavaScript object

First step would be to parse this parameter to an object easy to manipulate. [Other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6298103/1734119) asked how to do this, so you will only have to search a bit to find which is best for you. The one I found first uses [JQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/)'s [`deparam` function](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/deparam/), which is the reverse for [JQuery's `param` function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/). Parsing your URL parameter this way is easy:

```
var params = $.deparam(urlParam);
```

#### Extract minimums from each array

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8934895/1734119) (same method used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values)) showed how to add a function to the array prototype which would return the minimal element of the array.

```
Array.prototype.min = function() {
  return Math.min.apply(null, this);
};
```

If you go with it, getting the lowest element of your array is simple:

```
var lowestUnits = params.units.min();
```

Alternately, if you do not wish to add it to your prototype, you could call it explicitely:

```
var lowestUnits = Math.min.apply(null, params.units);
```

### Full code example

Concatenating the samples from other answers, here is would be how to go<sup>1</sup>:

#### Adding a `min` function to Array's prototype

```
Array.prototype.min = function() {
  return Math.min.apply(null, this);
};

// ...

var params = $.deparam('units[1]=5&grade[1]=1.25&units[2]=3&grade[2]=1.50&units[3]=2&grade[3]=2.50');
var lowestGrade = params.grade.min();
var lowestUnits = params.units.min();
```

#### Leaving prototype as is

```
var params = $.deparam('units[1]=5&grade[1]=1.25&units[2]=3&grade[2]=1.50&units[3]=2&grade[3]=2.50');
var lowestGrade = Math.min.apply(null, params.grade);
var lowestUnits = Math.min.apply(null, params.units);
```

---

<sub>1: Once again, [JQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/)'s [`deparam` function](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/deparam/) is not the only available solution.</sub>