# Why aren't parenthesis used in this instance of chaining built-in JavaScript methods

Tags: javascript, chaining, parentheses

I refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8934895/4275690

```
    Array.min = function( array ){
    return Math.min.apply( Math, array );
};
```

Howcome Math's min method doesn't require parenthesis before .apply() is chained onto it? My understanding of that syntax is that .min without parenthesis is a property.

My confusion arises because the majority of my experience with chaining comes from using jQuery with code similar to the following:

```
    jQuery("div").hide("slow", function(){
      jQuery(this)
      .addClass("done")
      .find("span")
      .addClass("done")
      .end()
      .show("slow", function(){
        jQuery(this).removeClass("done");
      });
    });
```

source: http://ejohn.org/blog/ultra-chaining-with-jquery/

Comment: It's not used there because it's not method chaining. Method chaining is when you call a method, then call another method on the result of that method, which may or may not be the original instance itself. In this case, the user isn't calling Math.min at first, they're just sort-of extracting it, and then applying it to an array of values. (There's only one call, not multiple chained calls.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.apply` isn't a chained call, it's a property of every `Function`, it being available because every function inherits from `Function.prototype`.

That is, given:

```
var m = Math.min;
```

Then `m.apply` is just accessing the `.apply` property of that function.

Answer (score -1):

Appending `()` to a property name takes the value of that property and tries to call it as a function.

Functions are objects, so can have properties of their own.

`apply` is a property of the `min` (and every other) function (i.e. it is not a property of the return value of calling `min`).

This has nothing to do with method chaining, which is where the return value of a method is the object upon which the method was called.