# Find the lowest among the next highest elements in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

**The question seems to be a bit weird. Never mind.**

This is an array

```
[2, 7, 5, 10]
```

If I want to get the next greater number after 2, here's my code

```
var MyArray = [2, 7, 5, 10];
var RandomNumber = 2;
var MinGreaterThanPos;

for (var i =0; i < MyArray.length; i++) {
    if (MyArray[i] <= RandomNumber) 
        continue;

    if (typeof(MinGreaterThanPos) == 'undefined' || MyArray[i] < MinGreaterThanPos)
    {
        MinGreaterThanPos = i;
    }
}

alert(MyArray[MinGreaterThanPos]);
```

It will return 7.

What if I want to get the lowest among the `greater` numbers after 2?

That means, `7, 5, 10` are greater than 2. But I want to get 5, since the difference between 5 and 2 is lesser than any of the rest comparing with 2.

How will I do that?

**Updated:**

Coming to this point so far, what if there are objects inside an array?

For example:

```
var MyArray = [{user: 1, position:2}, {user:2, position: 6}, {user:3, position: 4}];
```

I want to do the same thing only with `position`. If I choose position 2, then the next position I am hoping to get back is 4 and not 6.

Comment: When array is [5, 2, 7, 10], the result you expect is 7. right?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve your problem is the following. Initially, we extend the Array adding a min method, in order we get the minimum element of an array. This is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934877/obtain-smallest-value-from-array-in-javascript). Then we filter our array, in order we exlcude the enries that are less or equal to the number we hava as a *threshold*. Last we find the min number.

```js
Array.min = function( array ){
    return Math.min.apply( Math, array );
};

var numbers = [2, 7, 5, 10];
var number = 5;
var numbers = numbers.filter( function( n ){
     return n > number;
});
console.log( Array.min( numbers ) );
```

Comment: @SagnikChakraborti You could think of this based on the above example. `Hint`: focus on `filter` function, what does this function? A detailed explanation of this mehtod can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter. If you can't make it, just let me know.

Comment: For `number = 5`, it should return `7`, not `2`.

Comment: @georg hm...you are pretty correct ! Thank you very much for spotting this. I will correct it immediately

Answer (score 1):

first you sort the array then you get next of last item equal to `RandomNumber` if there is duplicates

```js
var MyArray = [2,2,2, 10, 7, 5,5,7,5];//to test duplicates
var RandomNumber = 2;
var srt = MyArray.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
var MinGreaterThanPos = srt[srt.lastIndexOf(RandomNumber)+1];


alert(MinGreaterThanPos);
```

Comment: Doesn't take duplicates into account

Comment: How? it should support duplicates see updated array.

Comment: i used `lastIndexOf()+1`

Comment: Yep, apologies.

Comment: No sir, glad to see your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

This returns the minimal of array elements greater than `el`:

```js
function minNext (a, el) {
  var min = Infinity;
  
  for (let x of a) {
    if (x > el && x - el < min - el)
      min = x;
  }
  
  return min;
}

//

let a = [1,9,2,8,3,-2,7,4,-3,6,5,5,5];
for (let x of a)
  console.log(x, minNext(a, x))
```

less efficient, but more idiomatic:

```
let minNext = (a, el) => Math.min.apply(0, a.filter(x => x > el));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
      var ar = [2,7,5,10];
      Math.min.apply(undefined, ar.filter(function(x,y){return y > 0}));
      //for any explanation, tell it in comment
```

Answer (score 0):

You might do like this in a single pass. It takes into account the duplicates as well;

```js
var arr = [2, 7, 5, 2, 10],
 result = arr.reduce((p,c) => c < p[0] ? (p[0] = c,p)
                                       : c < p[1] ? (p[0] !== c && (p[1] = c),p)
                                                  : p, [Infinity,Infinity])[1];
console.log(result);
```

As per objects as array items you simply the modify the code to show as follows;

```js
var arr = [{user: 1, pos:2}, {user:2, pos: 6}, {user:3, pos: 4}, {user:4, pos: 12}, {user:5, pos: 9}],
 result = arr.reduce((p,c) => c.pos < p[0].pos ? (p[0] = c,p)
                                               : c.pos < p[1].pos ? (p[0].pos !== c.pos && (p[1] = c),p)
                                                                  : p, [{pos:Infinity},{pos:Infinity}])[1];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first sort and then loop through the array and until you find the next larger value. This way you will always have the second lowest value even if you have multiple.

```
var MyArray = [2,7,5,10];
var RandomNumber = 2;
var MinGreaterThanPos;

sortedMyArray = MyArray.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
for(var i in sortedMyArray) {
    if (sortedMyArray[i] > RandomNumber) {
        MinGreaterThanPos = i;
        break;
    }
}
alert(sortedMyArray[MinGreaterThanPos]);
```

You can do the same for position as:

```
var MyArray = [{user: 1, position:2}, {user:2, position: 6}, {user:3, position: 4}];
var RandomNumber = 2;
var MinGreaterThanPos;

sortedMyArray = MyArray.sort(function(a, b){return a.position-b.position});
for(var i in sortedMyArray) {
    if (sortedMyArray[i].position > RandomNumber) {
        MinGreaterThanPos = i;
        break;
    }
};
alert(sortedMyArray[MinGreaterThanPos]);
```

And if your don't want to use RandomNumber

```
var MyArray = [{user: 1, position:2}, {user:2, position: 6}, {user:3, position: 4}];
var MinGreaterThanPos;

sortedMyArray = MyArray.sort(function(a, b){return a.position-b.position});
for(var i in sortedMyArray) {
    if (sortedMyArray[i].position > sortedMyArray[0].position) {
        MinGreaterThanPos = i;
        break;
    }
};
alert(sortedMyArray[MinGreaterThanPos]);
```

Comment: what if there are duplicates of the minimum value?

Comment: I have updated my reaction. I see in your post you will get the next large number of variable "RandomNumber". If that is not the case you can loop through the array until you find the next large number which is not equal to the first, in this case sorterMyArray[0].

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
function getItem(array, search) {
    return array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return a.position > search && (!r || r.position > a.position) ? a : r;
    }, undefined);
}

var array1 = [{ user: 1, position: 2 }, { user: 2, position: 6 }, { user: 3, position: 4 }],
    array2 = [{ user: 1, position: 2 }, { user: 2, position: 6 }, { user: 3, position: 4 }, { user: 4, position: 5 }];

console.log(getItem(array1, 2));
console.log(getItem(array2, 2));
```

Comment: If my array is `var array = [{ user: 1, position: 2 }, { user: 2, position: 6 }, { user: 3, position: 4 }, {user:4, position: 5}]` and I search for `number = 5`, then it's returning `undefined` where it should have returned `6`

Comment: i get the wanted result, please see third example.