# How to get two smallest numbers in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to get 2 smallest numbers out of 3 numbers and then want to display that 2 smallest numbers on the screen simply like in PHP we use simply echo to display the value on the screen. But with this code I get only one smallest value need to get and display 2 smallest values on the web page.

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
  var a = 5;
  var b = 4;
  var c = 6;
  var d = Math.min(a,b,c);
</script>
```

so the result should be "First smallest: 4" and "second smallest: 5"

Put these first & second lowest values in different variables like var first = 4 & var second = 5 and then should display like with PHP code `<?php echo $first;?>` and `<?php echo $second ; ?>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obtain smallest value from array in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934877/obtain-smallest-value-from-array-in-javascript)

Comment: no my question is different i need to get first smallest & second smallest numbers

Comment: Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mKGbg/4/)

Answer (score 5):

```
var n = 2; // size of min you want
var array = [2,3,4,5] , outarray=[];
var min;
for(i=0;i< n;i++){
    min = Math.min.apply(Math,array); 
    outarray.push(min);
    array.splice(array.indexOf(min), 1);
}
alert(outarray);
```

[JS Bin link](http://jsbin.com/hudadozoro/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: please use variable names not directly values in the array ans the values should display on screen without button click.Thanks & Regards

Comment: you can change what you want. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do it like below: (Pure js)

First sort the number array then loop over to find the required values

```js
function LowestAndSecondLowest(arr_num)
{
  arr_num.sort(function(x,y)
           {
           return x-y;
           });
  var uniqa = [arr_num[0]];
  var result = [];
  
  for(var j=1; j<arr_num.length; j++)
  {
    if(arr_num[j-1] !== arr_num[j])
    {
      uniqa.push(arr_num[j]);
    }
  }
  
  result.push("First smallest: "+uniqa[uniqa.length-arr_num.length],"second smallest: "+uniqa[1]);
  
  return result.join(' & ');
  
}
document.write(LowestAndSecondLowest([4,5,6]));
```

Comment: hello i need to pass the variable names a,b,c  as per my question variable names used here document.write(LowestAndSecondLowest([4,5,6])); in place of 4,5,6. Because these values will change everytime and the result should display on the same screen. please use the variable names reply me others fine. thanks & Regards.

Comment: you can pass variables like : `var a=4;
var b=5;
var c=6;
alert(LowestAndSecondLowest([a,b,c]));` @user7423894

Comment: sir can you please tell me that how can i get these 2 smallest values in 2 different variables in jQuery . Like 4 in var name = first & 5 in var name = second . please reply me.Thanks & Regards

Comment: and one thing more sire if the first & second variable values are nothing then display there 0 should not be null & should not be undefined.Regards

Comment: `var a = uniqa[uniqa.length-arr_num.length];` and `var b = uniqa[1];`

Comment: hello can you please tell me that how can i get var b = uniqa[1]; var b value & display with php eco . like <?php echo b ;?> . bcz i want to display the var b value with this <?php echo b ;?> .Please reply me .Thanks & Regards.

Comment: hello sir var a = uniqa[uniqa.length-arr_num.length]; and var b = uniqa[1]; this is not working aftyer that i am displaying these values with alert(a); & i get no results with this even there should be 4 in alert box for var a. please check this once & fix this in your above example so that i can check there that whats wrong im doing on my side. thanks & regards

Answer (score 0):

You can find maximum and remove it from array:

```
var a = 5, b = 4, c = 6;
var ar = [];
ar.push(a, b, c);
var max = Math.max(a, b, c);
ar.splice(ar.indexOf(max), 1);
var min1 = ar[0];
var min2 = ar[1];
```

Comment: please use variable names not directly values in the array. thanks & Regards