# Find the Sum of a certain key in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects:

```
let fileArray = [
  { filename: 'File1.txt', bytes: 12345, created: 1548360783511.728 },
  { filename: 'File2.txt', bytes: 34567, created: 1548361491237.182 },
  { filename: 'File3.txt', bytes: 23456, created: 1548361875763.893 },
  { filename: 'File4.txt', bytes: 56789, created: 1548360658932.682 }
];
```

The two things I am wanting to do with this array is to find the total bytes of all files in this array [sum of numbers](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp) and the File created first (smallest) [Obtain smallest value from array in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934877/obtain-smallest-value-from-array-in-javascript).

I was looking at array.reduce(), but that only appears to work on a flat array.  Can it work on specific keys of an array of objects or will I have to create a new temp array all values for that key in the current array and run array.reduce() on those values?

Comment: `reduce` works on *any* array. The only thing that changes is what the "current value" argument is. In your case, it would refer to an object. If `cur` was the current object, then `cur.bytes` would be the bytes. Your reduce would simply add `cur.bytes` to your accumulator.

Comment: That **is** a flat array.

Answer (score 0):

The old fahsioned way?

```
var totalBytes = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < fileArray.length; i++){
    totalBytes += fileArray[i].bytes;
}
console.log(totalBytes);
```

and

```
var firstFileIndex = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < fileArray.length; i++){
    if(fileArray[i].created < fileArray[firstFileIndex].created){
        firstFileIndex = i;
    }
}   
console.log(fileArray[firstFileIndex].filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example of how to do this with [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). First we create the two methods that will reduce the array, one for get the sum of `bytes`, and another for get the minimum `created`. Finally, we call reduce passing as argument the related reduce method.

```js
let fileArray = [
  {filename: 'File1.txt', bytes: 12345, created: 1548360783511.728},
  {filename: 'File2.txt', bytes: 34567, created: 1548361491237.182},
  {filename: 'File3.txt', bytes: 23456, created: 1548361875763.893},
  {filename: 'File4.txt', bytes: 56789, created: 1548360658932.682}
];

// Define reduce method for get the sum of bytes.

const reduceWithSumBytes = (res, {bytes}) => res += bytes;

// Define reduce method for get the minimum created.

const reduceWithMinCreated = (res, {created}) =>
{
    return res && (created < res ? created : res) || created;
};

// Use reduce() with the previous methods.

console.log(fileArray.reduce(reduceWithSumBytes, 0));
console.log(fileArray.reduce(reduceWithMinCreated, null));
```