# Get the element in the array with the max value of a property using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, minmax

I have an array of a custom JavaScript object which has a property named `order`. I have an array of this object, and I want to get the item with the highest "order".

Since I'm relatively new to jQuery, and coming from a C# background this is one of the instances where I highly appreciate LINQ :)

Anyway, to cut a long story short, I've checked the following links but they only return the value and not a reference of the array element itself... So a little help in changing that to return the element would be appreciated.

[jQuery min/max property from array of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052673/jquery-min-max-property-from-array-of-elements)

[element with the max height from a set of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060992/element-with-the-max-height-from-a-set-of-elements)

The custom object in question(which I have an array of) is as follows:

```
var severity = function (key, value, order) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
    this.order = order;
};
```

Comment: Give us a full code of what you have or a jsfiddle.net demo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find index of object in array with highest value in property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509075/find-index-of-object-in-array-with-highest-value-in-property)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe I got you wrong... but is that you are looking for?

```
function getHighest(array) {
    var max = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].order > (max.order || 0))
            max = array[i];
    }
    return max;
}

// var array = [object, object, object ...];
var highest = getHighest(array);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/c6gfj/

Answer (score 1):

```
array[array.map((o)=>o.order).indexOf(Math.max(...array.map((o)=>o.order)))]
```

## DEMO :

```js
let array=[{order:3},{order:5},{order:2},{order:2}];

console.log(
  array[array.map((o)=>o.order).indexOf(Math.max(...array.map((o)=>o.order)))]
)
```

Comment: I had an array with product_id and price values and this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sort array and pop the last object in array

```
function sortObj(a, b){
     return a.order < b.order ? 0 : 1;
}
obj.sort(sortObj)   
var highest =obj.pop();
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/VaYNb/

Answer (score 0):

use yourarray.sort().it will sort in ascending to descending order.its valid for 2-D arrays also.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
function getHighest(array, value){
  return array.sort(function(a,b){ b[value] - a[value] })[0];
}
```

Comment: sort is expensive to find the max value. You are doing more operations than what is needed.

Comment: Your sorting function isn't returning anything, and to get the highest value at index `0`, you'd need to do the less than comparison `<`, though subtraction would be better. `b[value] - a[value]`