# Find object having maximum value for the `id` property in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

In my array of objects, I want to find the object with the highest value for the `id` property.

Here is my array:

```
myArray = [
  {
    'id': '73',
    'foo': 'bar'
  },
  {
    'id': '45',
    'foo': 'bar'
  },
  // …
];
```

Generally, I use `$.grep` to find values in an array, like this:

```
var result = $.grep(myArray, function (e) {
    return e.id == 73;
});
```

But in this case I need to provide a specific `id` value for the object I want to select.

Answer (score 26):

The question states that he wants to find the *object* with the greatest id, not just the greatest id...

```
var myArray = [{'id':'73','foo':'bar'},{'id':'45','foo':'bar'}];

var max = myArray.reduce(function(prev, current) {
    if (+current.id > +prev.id) {
        return current;
    } else {
        return prev;
    }
});

// max == {'id':'73','foo':'bar'}
```

Answer (score 17):

```
const students = [
  { id: 100, name: 'Abolfazl', family: 'Roshanzamir' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Andy', family: 'Madadian' },
  { id: 1500, name: 'Kouros', family: 'Shahmir' }
]
```

If you want to find **the object with max Id** :

```
const item = students.reduce((prev, current) => (+prev.id > +current.id) ? prev : current)
 // it returns  { id: 1500, name: 'Kouros', family: 'Shahmir' }
```

If you want to find **the object with min Id** :

```
const item = students.reduce((prev, current) => (+prev.id < +current.id) ? prev : current)
// it returns {id: 2, name: "Andy", family: "Madadian"}
```

If you wnat to find **the max Id** :

```
const max = Math.max.apply(null, students.map(item => item.id));
// it returns 1500
```

If you want to find **the min Id** :

```
const min = Math.min.apply(null, students.map(item => item.id));
// it returns 2
```

Answer (score 13):

Use the [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method of the array. Using map you can provide a function that iterates over every element in the array. In that function, you can work out the object with the highest id. For example:

```
myArray = [{'id':'73','foo':'bar'},{'id':'45','foo':'bar'}];

var maxid = 0;

myArray.map(function(obj){     
    if (obj.id > maxid) maxid = obj.id;    
});
```

This will give you the max id of the objects in the array.

Then you can use grep to get the related object:

```
var maxObj = $.grep(myArray, function(e){ return e.id == maxid; });
```

Alternatively, if you just want the object with the max id, you can do this:

```
var maxid = 0;
var maxobj;

myArray.map(function(obj){     
    if (obj.id > maxid) maxobj = obj;    
});

//maxobj stores the object with the max id.
```

Comment: Use `forEach` instead of `map`. You don’t need to create an array filled with `undefined` that you immediately discard.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function reduceBy(reducer, acc) {
    return function(by, arr) {
        return arr[arr.reduce(function(acc, v, i) {
            var b = by(v);
            return reducer(acc[0], b) ? [b, i] : acc;
        }, acc || [by(arr[0]), 0])[1]];
    };
}
var maximumBy = reduceBy(function(a,b){return a<b;});


var myArray = [{'id':'73','foo':'bar'},{'id':'45','foo':'bar'}];
console.log(maximumBy(function(x){
    return parseInt(x.id,10)
}, myArray)); // {'id':'73','foo':'bar'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var max = 0;
var myArray = [{'id':'73','foo':'bar'},{'id':'45','foo':'bar'}]
var maxEle = myArray.map(function(ele){ if(ele.id>max){ max=ele} });
```

map is a function which iterates through array elements and performs specific operation.

Answer (score 1):

```
let id = items.reduce((maxId, item) => Math.max(maxId, item.id), 0);
```

or

```
let id = Math.max(...items.map(item => item.id).concat(0)); // concat(0) for empty array
// slimmer and sleeker ;)
let id = Math.max(...items.map(item => item.id), 0);
```

This way is more practical, because in the case of an empty array, it returns 0, unlike

```
Math.max.apply(null, [].map(item => item.id)) // -Infinity
```

and if you want to get "autoincrement", you can just add 1 regardless of whether the array is empty or not

```
// starts at 1 if our array is empty
autoincrement = items.reduce((maxId, item) => Math.max(maxId, item.id), 0) + 1;
```

---

**UPD:** Code with map is shorter but with **reduce** **is faster**, which is felt with large arrays

```js
let items = Array(100000).fill()
   .map((el, _, arr) => ({id: ~~(Math.random() * arr.length), name: 'Summer'}));
const n = 100;

console.time('reduce test');
for (let i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    let id = items.reduce((maxId, item) => Math.max(maxId, item.id), 0);
}
console.timeEnd('reduce test');

console.time('map test');
for (let i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    let id = Math.max(items.map(item => item.id).concat(0));
}
console.timeEnd('map test');

console.time('map spread test');
for (let i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    let id = Math.max(...items.map(item => item.id), 0);
}
console.timeEnd('map spread test');
```

> reduce test: 163.373046875ms
>   map test: 1282.745849609375ms
>   map spread test: 242.4111328125ms

If we create an even larger array, spread map will shutdown

```
let items = Array(200000).fill()
    .map((el, _, arr) => ({id: ~~(Math.random() * arr.length), name: 'Summer'}));
```

> reduce test: 312.43896484375ms
>   map test: 2941.87109375ms
>   Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>       at :15:32

Answer (score 1):

a shorten version using `reduce()`

```js
myArray.reduce((max, cur)=>(max.likes>cur.likes?max:cur))
```