# From an array of objects, how to return property `b` of the object that has the highest property `a`?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to get the value of the property `b` from the object with the highest value of the property `a`.

```
var myArr = [
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 15
  },
  {
    a: 2,
    b: 30
  }
];
```

I tried the following, but it just returns the highest value of `a`, rather than of `b`.

```
var res = Math.max.apply(Math,myArr.map(function(o){return o.a;});
var blah = getByValue(myArr);
```

Comment: And the problem is? That's a simple loop to find the object with the highest `a` value.

Comment: Related: [Find object having maximum value for id in array of javascript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22712691/4642212).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and on each iteration take the object with the highest `a` value:

```js
var myArr = [{"a":1,"b":15},{"a":2,"b":30}];

var result = myArr.reduce(function(o, o1) {
  return o.a > o1.a ? o : o1;
}).b;

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can sort a copy then get first or last depending on sort direction:

```js
var myArr = [
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 15
  },
  {
    a: 2,
    b: 30
  }
];

var highest = myArr.slice().sort((a,b)=>a.a-b.a).pop().b

console.log(highest)
```

Comment: Why do a full sort if you only need single item? Of course it is not a problem for 2 elements :) but still.

Answer (score 0):

### Using reduce

You can use `.reduce()` to find the element with the maximum `a` value and then just grab its `b` value, like this:

```js
var myArr = [{
    a: 1,
    b: 15
  },
  {
    a: 2,
    b: 30
  }
];

var max = myArr.reduce(function(sum, value) {
  return (sum.a > value.a) ? sum : value;
}, myArr[0]);

console.log(max.b);
```

### Using sort

A bit more unorthodox approach is to use `.sort()` to sort the array in descending order in terms of its property `a` and then get the first element's `b` value, like this:

```js
var myArr = [{
    a: 1,
    b: 15
  },
  {
    a: 2,
    b: 30
  }
];

var max = myArr.sort(function(value1, value2) {
  return value1.a < value2.a;
})[0];

console.log(max.b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myArr = [
    {
        a: 1,
        b: 15
    },
    {
        a: 2,
        b: 30
    }
];

var res = myArr.map(function(o){return o.b;});

myArr.sort(function (o1, o2) {
    return o1.a < o2.a;
})

console.log(myArr[0].b);
```