# Javascript - Who weighs the most? (Accessing all values in object of array with same key name)

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

```
let info = [
  {
    name: 'Harry Potter',
    weight: 160,
    hobby: 'quidditch',
  },
  {
    name: 'Hermione Granger',
    weight: 130,
    hobby: 'reading',
  }
  {
    name: 'Ronald Weasley',
    weight: 185,
    hobby: 'quidditch',
  }
]
```

How can I find out who weighs the most?

Thought process so far -- write code that will:

- list all the weights
- order them from greatest to smallest    *
- select the index of the number that is greatest [0]

So far, I'm stuck on the first step. I can access the specific weight of one character, but not all weights. I've tried this code:

```
const char_weight = data['weight']
console.log(char_weight)
```

But it's returning as 'undefined'.

Comment: So what is data?

Comment: are you familiar with for each loops?

Comment: This is also a dupe of [Find object having maximum value for id in array of javascript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22712691/4642212).

Answer (score 3):

There are more than few ways to do this. You can simply sort the array and then take the top entry.

```js
let info = [ { name: 'Harry Potter', weight: 160, hobby: 'quidditch', }, { name: 'Hermione Granger', weight: 130, hobby: 'reading', }, { name: 'Ronald Weasley', weight: 185, hobby: 'quidditch', } ]

console.log(info.sort((x,y) => y.weight - x.weight)[0])
```

Updates as per feedback.

Comment: `x.weight < y.weight` is a non-sensical return value for `sort`. `sort` expects a _number_, not a boolean. Use `y.weight - x.weight` instead. Also, take `[0]`, not `.slice(0, 1)`.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks!

Comment: this is a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through your array and get the index of the object that has the highest weight value. With the index you can then also access the other properties of the object. This method doesn't alter the array.

```
let index = 0;

for (let i = 1; i < info.length; i++) {
    if (info[index].weight < info[i].weight) {
        index = i;
    }
}
```

Now the index of the object with the highest weight value is stored in index and you can access the properties like that: info[index].name, info[index].weight, etc