# Node.js highest object value

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

With fs.readfile() i read an file and put the data of that file in an object. But how can i get the row with the highest value?

```
[ { id: 'AA', naam: 'de eerste', waarde: 100 },
  { id: 'BB', naam: 'de tweede', waarde: 120 },
  { id: 'CC', naam: 'de derde', waarde: 130 },
  { id: 'DD', naam: 'de laatste', waarde: 90 },
  { id: 'CC', naam: 'de derde', waarde: 150 },
  { id: 'CC', naam: 'de derde', waarde: 120 } ]
```

i mean the object row with the value of 150.

Comment: Not exact duplicate but you can refer to derive a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509075/find-index-of-object-in-array-with-highest-value-in-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate to @[Pranav C Balan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3037257/pranav-c-balan)'s answer could be use of `for` loop.

#### Logic

- Loop over Object and create a dummy variable to hold object with max value.
- Now on every iteration, if value is greater than current Max, replace dummy variable

```js
var data = [ { id: 'AA', naam: 'de eerste', waarde: 100 }, { id: 'BB', naam: 'de tweede', waarde: 120 }, { id: 'CC', naam: 'de derde', waarde: 130 }, { id: 'DD', naam: 'de laatste', waarde: 90 }, { id: 'CC', naam: 'de derde', waarde: 150 }, { id: 'CC', naam: 'de derde', waarde: 120 } ]

var result = data[0];

for(var i = 1; i< data.length; i++){
  if(result.waarde < data[i].waarde)
    result = data[i];
}

console.log(result)
```

Also note that objects are pass by reference, so if after the loop, you do `result.waarde = 0`, this will override object in `data` as well.

`result = data[i];` will just copy `reference` of `data[i]` in result and not entire object.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method to reduce into a single object by custom function.

```js
var data = [ { id: 'AA', naam: 'de eerste', waarde: 100 }, { id: 'BB', naam: 'de tweede', waarde: 120 }, { id: 'CC', naam: 'de derde', waarde: 130 }, { id: 'DD', naam: 'de laatste', waarde: 90 }, { id: 'CC', naam: 'de derde', waarde: 150 }, { id: 'CC', naam: 'de derde', waarde: 120 } ]

console.log(
  data.reduce(function(prev, next) {
    // compare object properties and return object with highest value
    return prev.waarde >= next.waarde ? prev : next;
  })
)
```

Comment: I have just formatted input data in 1 line so focus of answer remains on logic. If not required, please revert changes.