# Get element index of array of objects with the "highest" value for given key

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following array of objects:

```
[
   { name: 'january', score: 3.02 },
   { name: 'february', score: 1.02 },
   { name: 'march', score: 0 },
   { name: 'april', score: 12 },
]
```

What would be the quickest method for extract the position (`index`) of the element of the object with the highest score value...so, in the above case, the value would be index `3`...

N.B. Scores are dynamic, and the "winning" element is the highest value...

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: Iterate over the array and remember the highest value and the corresponding index.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find index of object in array with highest value in property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509075/find-index-of-object-in-array-with-highest-value-in-property)

Comment: The quickest in an unsorted list? Iterate and save. I mean... geez.

Comment: _“What would be the quickest method”_ - well write a couple different ones, and do a test using https://jsperf.com/ or something …?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the keys and reduce the indices by checking the score.

```js
var data = [{ name: 'january', score: 3.02 }, { name: 'february', score: 1.02 }, { name: 'march', score: 0 }, { name: 'april', score: 12 }],
    index = [...data.keys()].reduce((a, b) => data[a].score > data[b].score ? a : b);

console.log(index);
```

Comment: In your above example, what are you expecting the `var index` to be?

Comment: i expect `3`, because it has the hightest score of 12.

Comment: In my real world example, I always get 11 (which is the last element in the list). Perhaps because the scores are logged as floats?

Comment: Nope, apologies, this works! Being stupid - my key is `fuzzyRegexScore` and not `score` - a quick edit and boom! Works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = [
   { name: 'january', score: 3.02 },
   { name: 'february', score: 1.02 },
   { name: 'march', score: 0 },
   { name: 'april', score: 12 },
];

var resultValue = null;
var tempValue = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
data.forEach(function(element, index) {
    if(element.score > tempValue) {
        tempValue = element.score;
        resultValue = index;
    }
});

console.log(resultValue);
```

Comment: Since OP didn't state scores can't be negative I wouldn't make the assumption. There's a value for that.

Comment: That's not the value: `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`

Comment: This is great, and works. I'll let the communtiy vote to see if this should be the ideal winner over time. Thanks @caramba

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Use javascript max and map function to get value of index

```js
 var data = [
   { name: 'january', score: 3.02 },
   { name: 'february', score: 1.02 },
   { name: 'march', score: 0 },
   { name: 'april', score: 12 }
];

var maxValue = 
Math.max.apply(Math, data.map(function(row,index) { return index; }))


console.log(maxValue)
```

2) I think this will also give you correct result

```js
var data = [
   { name: 'april', score: 1 },
   { name: 'january', score: 3.02 },
   { name: 'february', score: 11.02 },
   { name: 'march', score: 2 }
   
];
var maxValue = Math.max.apply(Math, data.map(function(row) { return row.score; }))
var key = data.findIndex((row,index)=>{ if(row.score ===maxValue){return true}})

console.log(key)
```

Comment: This is the maxValue of the scores, I want to index of the highest scoring object. Thank you for the idea tho.

Comment: i have returned index from map not score try running code snippet

Comment: Hmmm, maybe because I have floats or something ... but using your example always returns 11.