# How do you find Min & Max of a property in an array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript object:

```
Person1.Name = "John";
Person1.Age = 12;

Person2.Name = "Joe";
Person2.Age = 5;
```

I then have an array of persons, how do I find the Min/Max based on a persons age?

Any solution in Javascript or Jquery is acceptable.

your help is much appreciated.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery min/max property from array of elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052673/jquery-min-max-property-from-array-of-elements)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare JavaScript Array of Objects to Get Min / Max](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864430/compare-javascript-array-of-objects-to-get-min-max)

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - I tried manually iterating through and finding Min/Max however Kooilnc's solution was the elegant solution I was after. :-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Say your array looks like this:

```
var persons = [{Name:"John",Age:12},{Name:"Joe",Age:5}];
```

then you can:

```
var min = Math.min.apply(null, persons.map(function(a){return a.Age;}))
   ,max = Math.max.apply(null, persons.map(function(a){return a.Age;}))
```

[**Edit**] Added ES2015 method:

```js
const minmax = (someArrayOfObjects, someKey) => {
  const values = someArrayOfObjects.map( value => value[someKey] );
  return {
      min: Math.min.apply(null, values), 
      max: Math.max.apply(null, values)
    };
};

console.log(
  minmax( 
    [ {Name: "John", Age: 12},
      {Name: "Joe", Age: 5},
      {Name: "Mary", Age: 3},
      {Name: "James sr", Age: 93},
      {Name: "Anne", Age: 33} ], 
    'Age') 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

First you sort the array with a [custom sorting function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```
var sorted = persons.sort(function(a, b) {
  if(a.Age > b.Age) return 1;
  else if(a.Age < b.Age) return -1;
  else return 0;
});
```

Then you can just take the first and last:

```
var min = sorted[0],
    max = sorted[sorted.length - 1];
```