# How to get biggest array element based on his second sub array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have an JavaScript array of arrays:

```
[[-786, 2], [-783, 1], [-782, 5], [-781, 1], [-779, 2], [-778, 1], [-775, 1], [-774, 1], [-773, 1], [-771, 2], [-769, 1], [-767, 1], [-766, 1], [-763, 2], [-760, 2]]
```

How can I get the biggest element based on value of second element in sub array?

In case above I want to get element:

```
[-782, 5]
```

Because 5 is biggest second value in all sub arrays.
If there will more than one sub arrays with the bigger second value, I'd like to get first one.

Mariusz

Comment: Have you checked this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052673/jquery-min-max-property-from-array-of-elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perform a descending sort based on the second element of each element of the array.

```
var array = [[-786, 2], [-783, 1], [-782, 5], [-781, 1], [-779, 2], [-778, 1], [-775, 1], [-774, 1], [-773, 1], [-771, 2], [-769, 1], [-767, 1], [-766, 1], [-763, 2], [-760, 2]];


array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b[1] - a[1];
});

console.log(array[0]);
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LWByU/)

Please note that while this solution is terse, using sort just for finding the largest or smallest element would be much slower than a `for` loop that finds the largest/smallest element in a single iteration.

Comment: In an interview your will not be allowed to use **sort** , it is also highly not recommended to use sort as it is very slow.

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = [[-786, 2], [-783, 1], [-782, 5], [-781, 1], [-779, 2], [-778, 1], [-775, 1], [-774, 1], [-773, 1], [-771, 2], [-769, 1], [-767, 1], [-766, 1], [-763, 2], [-760, 2]];
var maxElementIndex = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i][1] > array[maxElementIndex][1]) {
        maxElementIndex = i;
    }
}

console.log(array[maxElementIndex]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is tagged [d3](/questions/tagged/d3) you could also use [`d3.greatest()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#greatest) from the [d3-array](https://github.com/d3/d3-array) module [v2.3.0](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/releases/tag/v2.3.0) (emphasis mine):

> Returns the greatest element of the specified *iterable* according to the specified *comparator* or ***accessor***.

By providing an accessor function that returns the second element from each element's array `d3.greatest()` will return the element having the greatest value comparing all second elements.

```js
const data = [[-786, 2], [-783, 1], [-782, 5], [-781, 1], [-779, 2], [-778, 1], [-775, 1], [-774, 1], [-773, 1], [-771, 2], [-769, 1], [-767, 1], [-766, 1], [-763, 2], [-760, 2]];

const greatest= d3.greatest(data, d => d[1]);

console.log(greatest);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-array@2.4.0/dist/d3-array.min.js"></script>
```

Note, however, that at the time of writing `d3.greatest()` is not yet part of the D3 **v5** main bundle, you have you use the d3-array module. It should be included in the upcoming **v6**, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
var target = [[-786, 2], [-783, 1], [-782, 5], [-781, 1], [-779, 2], [-778, 1], [-775, 1], [-774, 1], [-773, 1], [-771, 2], [-769, 1], [-767, 1], [-766, 1], [-763, 2], [-760, 2]]
var max = 0, tmp = 0;
var max_entry, tmp_entry;
while (target.length > 0){
  tmp_entry = target.pop();
  tmp = tmp_entry[1];
  if (tmp > max){
      max = tmp;
      max_entry = tmp_entry;
  }
}
alert(max_entry);
```