# How can I read out the width of all child in an html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, width

I wanted to write a JavaScript (jQuery)-Function to read out the width of each child and childrens-childs to get the maxWidth of all child (and childrens-childs) from a i.e. div-element.

here my code so far:

```
function setBodyMinWidth(name){
var max = 0;
$(name).find('*').each(fucntion(){
    var width = $(this).outerWidth(true);
    if (width > max){
        max = width;
    }
});
$("body").css("minWidth", max+"px");
```

but it seems not to work.
My problem is, that in my website my `float: "right";`-content is over the pagecontent if the browsers-wndow is to small.
my page is under construction online, if u need some source-code, feel free to have a look [here](http://gurkentruppe.com/index.php?content=tow).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052673/jquery-min-max-property-from-array-of-elements

Answer (score 0):

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jdc98/)

markup:

```
<body>
    <div class=one >content1</div>
    <div class=two >content2</div>
</body>
```

css

```
.one {width: 50px;}
.two {width: 70px;}
```

js

```
var max = 0;
$('body').find('div').each(function(){
    var width = $(this).outerWidth(true);
    if (width > max){
        max = width;
    };
});
alert(max);
$("body").css("minWidth", max+"px");
```